# How can I make ivy not to put "-" at the end of jar files?

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using ivy with ant in my project. In ivy settings file I defined the resolvers as:

`<filesystem name="blabla">
           <artifact pattern="$repdirectory/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
</filesystem>`

and in my build xml I used:

`<ivy:retrieve pattern="$somedirectory/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" conf="asd"/>`

to retrieve the jar files.

The problem is: for example I have a jar file called example.jar but ivy downloads it as example-.jar. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Is this a JAR you've published with Ivy? If so, you should really publish with the version number as part of the JAR name. Sounds like you have an empty version number in the build that publishes it.

Comment: I reckon the confusion is caused by the optional revision in the filesystem resolver. Ivy is designed to managed versioned dependencies. My recommendation is to either have revision numbers or choose to live without them.

Comment: SteveD, that is not a jar I have published with ivy. So, there is no way to avoid this behaviour, I think...